# Isolating/Shielding CPUs Allocated To Docker Container with Cgroup V2

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cgroups, cpuset

I am currently deploying a docker container on Ubuntu 22.04 (Using Cgroup v2) with the following command:

```
docker run --name=testapp --cpuset-cpus=35,39 -it testapp
```

Is there any way at runtime I can ensure no Linux process can use cpus 35 and 39 except for my docker container above?

I believe for Cgroup v1 systems, one could use cset shielding to perform this task but the cset/cpuset Python app doesn't seem to work with Cgroup v2 currently.

The only way I can currently see a viable solution, is going into every process in `/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice` (except for my docker container `/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-17321ee94...`) and adding every cpu except for 35 and 39 into `cpuset.cpus` but this seems like a lot of work just to isolate one process/container.

I also understand the kernel boot param `isolcpus` can be used but that does not provide any runtime configuration which limits its usability

Comment: Does the process within the docker container fork? If not, you could find out the PID of that process and run cpuset-shield in PID mode. Example: `cset shield --shield --pid 1234`

Comment: I'm afraid `cset` doesn't work with Cgroup V2, when I run your command, I get a big error: 
""mount: /cpusets: none already mounted on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service.
cset: **> mount of cpuset filesystem failed, do you have permission? ""

Comment: If you do know a way to get cset/cpuset working with Cgroup v2 on Ubuntu 22.04, please do let me know!